# Isolate the time series data for a given category and apply a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the time series data that are related to several categories. I want to keep all categories in the same data frame. However, I need to apply time series analysis for each category individually.

Here is the example of data frame I am working with:

```
date_list = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/10/2018')
 txt = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A']
 val = np.random.randint(100, size=10)
 records = range(0,10)
 d = {'Date': date_list,'ID': txt, 'value': val, 'recnum': records}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
 print(df)
```

The next step is to apply a function to time series data related to each category. I want to use shift(). Here is the slow way to get the desired output:

```
base = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for item in base:
    temp = df[df.ID == item].set_index('recnum')['value']
    mapper = temp.shift(periods=1)
    df[item + '_shifted'] = df.recnum.map(mapper)
    print(df)
```

I expect that this code will run very slowly on the 5M row dataset. I was wondering if there are faster ways to compute the same thing.

Comment: I found some typos in my code - I fixed them. also - changed the code slightly to make it look more professional.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another approach. I remember that dictionary object is much faster when it comes to mapping it to a data frame.

```
    dic = {}
    rec = pd.Series([])

    for item in base:
    temp = df[df.ID == item]['value']
    mapper = temp.shift(periods=1)
    dic[item] = mapper
    rec = rec.append(dic[item]) 

df['new'] = df.recnum.map(rec)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this out and see if its any faster:

```
def shift_frame(g):
    item = g['ID'].iloc[0]
    g[item + '_shifted'] = g['value'].shift(periods=1)
    return g

df.groupby('ID', sort=False).apply(shift_frame)
```